# google analytics real time leaving entire /search directory out

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a /search directory. All the pages there are using url rewrites to the index.php page. Expect for the page color.php which is a "search landing page" of sorts.

In the index.php page I put the search term in the trackpage like this:

```
gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/search/index.php?q={$search_form.query}']);
```

that's in a smarty template so the search_form.query is replaced with the actual query.

In the color.php page -- and in the rest of the entire site I write out this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Every single page a user hits in the web site shows up in google analytics real time. Expect pages in the /search subdirectory. Why? What's wrong?

These pages ARE tracked as I can see them in the content reports, and i have google tracking site search via the q parameter. All of it shows up in all the other reports. It just doesn't show up in the real time reports.

Can someone help me out? Why is this happening?

Comment: no one has an answer to this? It's really bugging me. Why won't this work?

Comment: I've asked over in the google analytics message board and no one has an answer. This doesn't make any sense. It shouldn't matter that the page is /search/ it's still a page. It should show up in real time.